# extracting substring

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following file

```
Nt01    maker   mRNA    143295  155540  .   +   .   ID=Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1;Parent=Nitab4.5_0006317g0010;Name=Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1;_AED=0.08;_eAED=0.08;_QI=0|0.45|0.25|1|0.90|0.75|12|0|1011;Note="Peptidase S59%2C nucleoporin"
Nt01    maker   mRNA    170633  173860  .   +   .   ID=Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1;Parent=Nitab4.5_0006317g0020;Name=Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1;_AED=0.26;_eAED=0.26;_QI=15|0|0|0.83|0.6|0.33|6|0|424;Note="Putative S-adenosyl-L-methionine-dependent methyltransferase"
```

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {print $1,$9,$4,$5}' test.txt | head
Nt01    ID=Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1;Parent=Nitab4.5_0006317g0010;Name=Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1;_AED=0.08;_eAED=0.08;_QI=0|0.45|0.25|1|0.90|0.75|12|0|1011;Note="Peptidase S59%2C nucleoporin" 143295  155540
Nt01    ID=Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1;Parent=Nitab4.5_0006317g0020;Name=Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1;_AED=0.26;_eAED=0.26;_QI=15|0|0|0.83|0.6|0.33|6|0|424;Note="Putative S-adenosyl-L-methionine-dependent methyltransferase"  170633  173860
```

How is it possible to shorten it to this:

```
Nt01    Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1 143295  155540
Nt01    Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1 170633  173860
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the spaces in your input are tabs and you want the output tab-separated too:

```
$ awk -F'[\t=;]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $10, $4, $5}' file
Nt01    Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1 143295  155540
Nt01    Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1 170633  173860
```

Answer (score 2):

Invoking **GNU sed** with extended regex support on `-E`:

```
# field construction helper variables
t=$'\t'; T="[^$t]"; F=$T+$t
F2=$F$F; F3=$F2$F; FT=$F$T+

# use the helper variables in rearranging
# and pruning the pattern space
sed -Ee "
  s/^($F)$FT($t$FT)$t${F3}ID=([^;]*);.*/\1\3\2/
" file.tsv
```

**Results:**

```
Nt01    Nitab4.5_0006317g0010.1 143295  155540
Nt01    Nitab4.5_0006317g0020.1 170633  173860
```